# charAt() issues

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I'm writing a program that decodes a secret message from a text file that is redirected from the command line. First line is a key phrase and the second is a set of integers that index the key phrase. I am trying to use the `charAt()` method but I keep getting a no such element exception error message.

```
public class Decoder 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (keyboard.hasNext())
        {
           String phrase = keyboard.nextLine();
           int numbers = keyboard.nextInt();
           char results = phrase.charAt(numbers); 
               System.out.print(results); 
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: what's the test case for which this fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you do `int numbers = keyboard.nextInt();`, it  reads only the `int` value (and skips the `\n` which is the enter key you press right after) - See [`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29).

So when you continue reading with `keyboard.nextLine()` you receive the `\n`.

You can add another `keyboard.nextLine()` in order to read the skipped `\n` from `nextInt()`.

The exception you're getting is because you're trying to use `charAt` on `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind `charAt` is zero-indexed.

e.g. If you type "test", and then "3", the output should be "t".

Comment: Line 1= five hexing wizard bots jump quickly
Line 2= 21 5 6 11 15 9 10 3 34 22 28 5 15 2 3 4 21 5 3 18 27 5 20 9 6 23 19 20 7

here is the text file it is being read from. I want to get each int and use the charAt to reference the first line and output what that character is to form the message.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at Decoder.main(Decoder.java:22)

These are the messages i keep getting.